# Combining all JS and CSS files into one

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, gruntjs

**UPDATE**
There are multiple subfolders and html files. Each have their JS files and css files. Currently, I am minifying each and let them remain separated.

Inside my html code there are lot of `<link>` and `<script>` tags. This impact the page load time due to multiple HTTP requests during initial page load. I want combine all JS and CSS files that are related to one html page into one and update the code to point to one `<script>` and `<link>` tag.

**Original Question**
I need to combine all CSS and JS files into one file like allcss.css and alljs.js.
I am using grunt to minify my files. Is there a way to combine all files and update the code to point to allcss.css in html code?

I wanted to use grunt-contrib-concat but not sure if it would update HTML code or not.

Currently I am minifying my individual files like:

```
cssmin: {
   minify: {
    options: {
    },
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'minifiedbuild', 
    src: '**/*.css',
    dest: 'minifiedbuild/',
    ext: '.css'
  }
 },
 uglify: {
   options: {
     mangle: {
      toplevel: true
     },
     compress: {
        global_defs: {
          'DEBUG': false
        },
        dead_code: true,
        drop_console: true,
        drop_debugger: true,
        conditionals: true,
        comparisons: true,
        toplevel: true,
        join_vars: true,
        if_return: true,
        cascade: true,
        collapse_vars: true,
        reduce_vars: true
    }
   },
   my_target: {
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'minifiedbuild',
        src: ['!node_modules/*.js', '**/*.js'],
        dest: 'minifiedbuild/'
      }]
    }
 },
 htmlmin: {
    dist: {                                      
      options: {                                 
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyJS: true
      },
      files: [
        {
          expand: true,    
          cwd: 'minifiedbuild',      
          src: ['**/*.html'], 
          dest: 'minifiedbuild/',  
        },
  ],                
    }
 },
```

I don't want developers to make code changes as it would be a huge task at their end.

Comment: I don't understand. You can just add the minify code  `<script src="minifiedbuild/all.js"></script>` inside the head tag ?

Comment: For css you can use a css pre-processor like less or sass to import all your css files, then just render the 1 less/sass file with grunt. You will want to minify your output file after combining.

For javascript you should look into a javascript bundler, such as `CommonJS`

Comment: Compile your code with Bazel: https://bazel.build/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664662/minify-some-files-combine-all-with-grunt-js

Comment: please see updated description